How to count all instances of two different entries that should've been one?
I apologize if this is a silly question, but I've recently started to learn SQL and I'm currently trying to clean a dataset.
However, some entries have mistakes like having a ' ' after the text (I guess). My goal is to count all instances of each entry, but in this example I have two instances of '4wd' coming up. How can I make them the same?here is a screenshot of the query and the resulting table
I don't know many commands yet, so I tried WHERE SUBSTRING(drive_wheels, 1, 3) = '4wd'. This didn't work, and even if it did I guess it would've only given me the count for '4wd', so I'm lost... Thanks in advance!

I think I've just got it!! I tried:
SELECT
TRIM(drive_wheels),
COUNT(TRIM(drive_wheels))
FROM
automobiles
GROUP BY
TRIM(drive_wheels)
And it counted all instances of '4wd' as a single entity!

I would just fix the data: UPDATE MY_TABLE SET drive_wheels = TRIM(drive_wheels)

My previous solution of fixing the data while querying does not clean the data for future instances, so I tried following your (@Bohemian) suggestion of fixing the data before querying, but got an error. "ERROR:  source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression
LINE 4:  (drive_wheels) = TRIM(drive_wheels)".  Can you help me understand why? Thanks ;)

Show the full query that's giving you the error.

I'm so sorry, I had (drive_wheels) = TRIM(drive_wheels) instead of drive_wheels = TRIM(drive_wheels) ‍♂️

To prevent future data having extra whitespace, you could either a) fix the code that's not trimming before writing it to the DB (recommended), or b) create a trigger that does the trimming on insert.

Like you discovered in a comment, you can fix the data while you query them, for example by trimming leading and trailing blanks:
SELECT trim(drive_wheels), count(*)
FROM automobiles
GROUP BY trim(drive_wheels);

It might be better to sanitize the data with an UPDATE.
To avoid such problems, there are several techniques:

you can use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to fix the data as they are inserted

you can use a check constraint to throw an error if there is a spelling mistake

rather than storing a string, you can create a lookup table with allowed values and store that table's numeric primary key rather than a string



Thank you! However, most of you proposed is still beyond my current level of knowledge  Please correct me if I'm wrong, from what I understood the first 2 suggestions are preventive, right? The first would make the data conform to my standards while inputing it, the second would alert me of any mistakes while inputing, is that it? The 3rd suggestion is just way to much for my current understanding, though.

The first method fixes the data when they are inserted. The second throws an error if you insert bad data. The third prevents bad data, because you cannot even insert them. To explain the third option, think about a form where you have to enter the data. The lookup table is like a drop-down list, and you have to select one of the offered values and cannot choose anything else.
